# How can I prevent leading spaces when transforming integer columns to character in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a data.frame with character and integer columns. I want to transform them all into characters, but I get unwanted leading spaces for the numeric columns:

```
> example <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10,c=rep("foo",10))
> apply(example,2,format,trim=T)
      a    b    c    
 [1,] " 1" " 1" "foo"
 [2,] " 2" " 2" "foo"
 [3,] " 3" " 3" "foo"
 [4,] " 4" " 4" "foo"
 [5,] " 5" " 5" "foo"
 [6,] " 6" " 6" "foo"
 [7,] " 7" " 7" "foo"
 [8,] " 8" " 8" "foo"
 [9,] " 9" " 9" "foo"
[10,] "10" "10" "foo"
```

The `trim=T` parameter is ignored apparently. This only occurs in the presence of the character column `'c'`, i.e. it works fine if `'c'` is not present (`apply(example[,-3],...)`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, it's because of `as.matrix`, but you can bypass this by using `sapply`:

```
> sapply(example, format, trim = TRUE)
      a    b    c    
 [1,] "1"  "1"  "foo"
 [2,] "2"  "2"  "foo"
 [3,] "3"  "3"  "foo"
 [4,] "4"  "4"  "foo"
 [5,] "5"  "5"  "foo"
 [6,] "6"  "6"  "foo"
 [7,] "7"  "7"  "foo"
 [8,] "8"  "8"  "foo"
 [9,] "9"  "9"  "foo"
[10,] "10" "10" "foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay with a character matrix as an output (you seem to be based on your use of `apply`, try):

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(example, as.character))
```

This produces:

```
      a    b    c    
 [1,] "1"  "1"  "foo"
 [2,] "2"  "2"  "foo"
 [3,] "3"  "3"  "foo"
 [4,] "4"  "4"  "foo"
 [5,] "5"  "5"  "foo"
 [6,] "6"  "6"  "foo"
 [7,] "7"  "7"  "foo"
 [8,] "8"  "8"  "foo"
 [9,] "9"  "9"  "foo"
[10,] "10" "10" "foo"
```

Comment: +1 Just noticed that you posted this just before me. My answer isn't much different...

Comment: Perhaps even `sapply(example, as.character)` to save some typing ;)

Answer (score 1):

As it says in `?apply`, the first argument is coerced to a matrix.  In this case, it converts it to a character matrix because of column `c`.  The call to `as.matrix` creates the leading spaces. The subsequent calls to `format` do nothing because the data are already character.

```
> as.matrix(example)
      a    b    c    
 [1,] " 1" " 1" "foo"
 [2,] " 2" " 2" "foo"
 [3,] " 3" " 3" "foo"
 [4,] " 4" " 4" "foo"
 [5,] " 5" " 5" "foo"
 [6,] " 6" " 6" "foo"
 [7,] " 7" " 7" "foo"
 [8,] " 8" " 8" "foo"
 [9,] " 9" " 9" "foo"
[10,] "10" "10" "foo"
```

Without column `c`, it's converted to an integer matrix, and `format` converts the integers to character.

```
> as.matrix(example[,-3])
       a  b
 [1,]  1  1
 [2,]  2  2
 [3,]  3  3
 [4,]  4  4
 [5,]  5  5
 [6,]  6  6
 [7,]  7  7
 [8,]  8  8
 [9,]  9  9
[10,] 10 10
```

Better to simply use `lapply`:

```
example <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=1:10,c=rep("foo",10))
example[] <- lapply(example, format, trim=TRUE)
# use sapply if you really want a matrix
example <- sapply(example, format, trim=TRUE)
```

Comment: +1 for actually referring to something from the man pages rather than me just saying I seem to remember :-)